# set ng-grid to a vertical layout to have Row headers instead of column headers

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have an ng-grid 2.0.12 that I want to have first column rows as headers. So basically have a vertical table. Is there a way to achieve this in ng-grid?

```
.controller('ReportA', function($scope,$http, DaService, reportFactoryTable, trendReportFactoryTable) {

    $scope.filterOptions = {
        filterText: "",
        useExternalFilter: true
    }; 

        $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'aData',

        jqueryUITheme: true,
        enablePinning: true, 
        showFooter: true,
        enableRowSelection: false,     
        filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions, 
        plugins: [new ngGridCsvExportPlugin()],  
        columnDefs: [
        {field: "item1", width: 120 },
        {field: "item2", width: 120 },
        {field: "item3", width: 120 },
        {field: "item4", width: 120 },
        {field: "item5", width: 120 },

        ]
    };

$scope.toggleCol= function(i){
    $scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.columns[i].toggleVisible();
};
```